# Accept both int and class in variadic templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Wrestling templates for this one function is proving to be beyond me.

---

#### What I want:

A function that produces the same float type as the one given to it inside any of the following containers:

- `vector<ANY_FLOAT_TYPE>`
- `array<ANY_FLOAT_TYPE, N>`

(I'm open to having it accept even more containers, of course!)

---

#### The Problem:

The problem lies with array<> accepting an integer as its second template argument while vector<> accepts an allocator in that position. How do I write a templated function that can accept both typenames and ints for a single argument? Or is this the wrong way to proceed and write this function?

I could just copy-paste and write the function twice, both for `vector<>`s and `array<>`s, but that's no solution...

> ```
> template <typename FT, typename CONT_T, typename... Ts>
> FT float_sum( CONT_T<FT, Ts...> xs ) {
>
>     // WARNING: not an accurate summation algorithm!
>     return accumulate( xs.begin(), xs.end(), 0 );
>
>     //////////////
>     static_assert( is_floating_point<FT>::value, "sum() only accepts floating point types." );
> }
> ```

Comment: Standard containers are basically required (I think?) to have an alias called value_type which says what they contain. You can just use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take the entire container as a template parameter and instead use `value_type`, which is part of the interface for all [Container types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container). Something like

```
template <typename Container>
auto sum(Container const &container)
    -> typename Container::value_type
{
  using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
  static_assert(std::is_floating_point<value_type>::value, 
                "only for floating types");

  return std::accumulate(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), value_type{});
}
```

Also, if you decide you eventually also want to sum containers with non-floating types using some other specialization, you may opt to drop the static assertion in favor of [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), or (by C++20) Concepts. With the [Concepts TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf) available in GCC >= 6:

```
template <typename Container>
auto sum(Container const &container)
requires 
    std::is_floating_point<typename Container::value_type>::value    
{
  using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
  return std::accumulate(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), value_type{});  
}
```